# file upload with special characters in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, xpages-ssjs

In Xpages Upload control,I can upload the photo file with special characters. But In the view, some of the special characters change to underscore (eg. {#[ to _ ) , some are not (like space,+). When using the function attachmentObject.getName() , I can get the original file name with special characters. Therefore I got a problem when i get back that kind of file. Is there any suggestion for me?? Thank You.

Comment: attachmentObject.getHref()?

Comment: attachmentObject is aNotesEmbeddedObject

Comment: Do you meant you want to download the photo you just uploaded or you want to display the photo in the view?

Comment: I want to display that photo on the xpage. so I use .getName() to get that image file. So I get the original file name with special characters. But in the view that image file is saved with _ underscore instance of special characters. Therefore I faced with error.

Comment: Since you want a suggestion, you could probably rename the file if it contains special character. The fileUpload control has that property. Maybe if your filename has special character, only then you rename it. You can get hold of the filename you just uploaded by following these examples: http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/m.leusink/entry/processing_files_uploaded_to_an_xpage?lang=en

Comment: Yes. If special characters can not get I should change the file name. But the one thing is that I can not use the local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT . I got the error. Because I am not on local.

Comment: Hi, you can get the name of the attachment in the richtextitem by using: `RichTextItem.getEmbeddedObjects().firstElement().getName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the hash (#) as this is a very special character in URLs. It cannot be easily translated into the special URL-Encoded form as it is a valid character for the URL scheme and has a special meaning there. Using the ExtLib @EncodeUrl function does also not work as this one will cut your string off right in front of that hash (which i consider a bug), leading to a resource request that cannot exist on your server and hence leading to a 404.

In order to finally solve this, I took an old function that I wrote back in 2009 (http://blog.gollmick.de/mgoblog.nsf/dx/some-more-Functions-for-XPages-URLEncode-URLDecode.htm) - and that one does the job as you need it here:

1. get the attachment name
2. encode the attachment name correctly
3. compute a resource path relative to the database and add the encoded attachment name

Assuming that your datasource is named `document1` and you have the attachment in an item named `body` and you are going to use the very first attachment of that item, you would need the following code to compute the path to your attachment correctly:

```
function @URLEncode(encodeObject, encSch:String) {
    try {
            var encScheme = ((encSch) && (encSch !== null))?encSch:"UTF-8";
            return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(encodeObject.toString(),
                    encScheme);
    } catch (e) {
            print("ERROR in @URLEncode:" + e);
    }
    return null;
}

try {
var list:java.util.List = document1.getAttachmentList("Body"),
    neo:NotesEmbeddedObject,
    size = list.size(),
    path = "";
if (0 < size) {
    neo = list.get(0);
    path = "0/" + document1.getDocument().getUniversalID() + "/$file/" + @URLEncode(neo.getName());
}
return path;
} catch (e) {
print(e.toString());
}
```

You will certainly need to modify this code to your needs, but this should give you the right hint for computing the right path for web. I have not yet tested that one in XPinC right now, so the computed path may still differ here.